# PHP How do I add an object to an array?

Tags: php

**Expected Result:**
I have several echo statements and I should be getting something like this:

```
index1
Question->addChoice1
Choice1
Choice2
Question->addChoice2
index2
```

**Actual Results:**

```
index1
Question->addChoice1
Choice1
Choice2
```

Its failing at:

```
$this.$choices[] = new Choice($obj);
```

I have no idea why its doing this, but its almost 3AM here so maybe I'm just too brain-dead to see it. please help.

index.php

```
    $QUESTIONS = array();
    for ($chapter=1; $chapter<=count($max_chapter); $chapter++) {
        $question_qry = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_questions WHERE chapter=$chapter ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT $max_chapter[$chapter]";
        $question_req = mysql_query($question_qry);
        while ($question_obj = mysql_fetch_object($question_req)) {
            $newQuestion = new Question($question_obj);
            $choice_qry = "SELECT * FROM $tbl_choices WHERE question=$question_obj->reference ORDER BY choice ASC;";
            $choice_req = mysql_query($choice_qry);
            while ($choice_obj = mysql_fetch_object($choice_req)) { 
                echo "index1<br>";
                $newQuestion->addChoice($choice_obj);
                echo "index2<br>";
            }
            $QUESTIONS[] = $newQuestion;
            echo '<pre>'; print_r($newQuestion); echo '</pre>';
        }
    }
    shuffle($QUESTIONS);
    echo '<pre>'; print_r($QUESTIONS); echo '</pre>';
```

question.php

```
class Question {
    private $chapter;
    private $topic;
    private $reference;
    private $question_name;
    private $question_correct;
    private $special;
    private $pic;
    private $choices = array();

    function __construct($obj) {
        $this->chapter          = $obj->chapter;
        $this->topic            = $obj->topic;
        $this->reference        = $obj->reference;
        $this->question_name    = $obj->question_name;
        $this->question_correct = $obj->question_correct;
        $this->special          = $obj->special;
        $this->pic              = $obj->pic;
    }

    public function addChoice($obj){
        echo "Question->addChoice1<br>";
        $this.$choices[] = new Choice($obj);
        echo "Question->addChoice2<br>";
    }
```

...

choice.php

```
class Choice {
    private $chapter;
    private $question;
    private $choice;
    private $choice_name;
    private $choice_explanation;

    function __construct($obj) {
        echo "Choice1<br>";
        $this->chapter            = $obj->chapter;
        $this->question           = $obj->question;
        $this->choice             = $obj->choice;
        $this->choice_name        = $obj->choice_name;
        $this->choice_explanation = $obj->choice_explanation;
        echo "Choice2<br>";
    }
```

...

[Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ph641.png)

Comment: It seems your syntax is incorrect, try `$this->choices[] = new Choice($obj);` instead of `$this.$choices[] = new Choice($obj);`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In PHP you have to use `->` to call object properties, not `.`. `.` is concatenation.

So just replace `$this.$choices[]` with `$this->choices[]`

Typical typo for people who haven't worked much with PHP, but have experience in other languages.

Comment: that was it.... 1 hour of suffering... 15min to write this up... 60 seconds to get an answer

Comment: Glad I have helped you. If you would tick the answer, I would be grateful too :) @DericMccadden